# Ant design mobile failed to work in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd, antd-mobile

[output of genymotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8G5Z.png)

[content of .babelrc and the window of genymotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB2Se.png)

[content of App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1wnJ.png)

I simply import Button from antd-mobile in a project of react native and use it like this. Why does such things happen? I have already installed babel-plugin-import, react-dom, antd-mobile. And I have changed .babelrc as showed above.

Comment: I changed ant-mobile to ant-mobile-rn and it works!

Comment: I dont think you need react-dom using react-native :) if you found the solution, should answer it yourself, and then mark the question as resolved, you now as the SO style :D

Comment: Sorry, I just have no idea of how should one behave in stackoverflow. I will never make mistake like this one. And the solution is changing ant-mobile to ant-mobile-rn. It works for me.

Comment: No problem friend, we all learning always :D. Good choise ant-design-rn it's awesome !

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ant Design Mobile RN](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile-rn), Specifically designed for React Native.